# TFS 2013 build agents sharing common build folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm using TFS 2013 on premises. I have four build agents configured on a Build machine. Several build definitions compile ASP .NET websites. I configured the msbuild parameters to deploy the IIS application to the integration server, which sits out there in Rackspace.

By default webdeploy does differential deployments by comparing file dates. In my case that's a big plus because copying files from our network to Rackspace takes quite some time. Now, in order to preserve file dates the build agent has to compile the same base set of source code. On every build only the differential source code yields a new DLL, minimizing the number of files deployed.

All of that works fine, with a caveat: a given build definition has to be assigned to a build agent (by agent name or tag). The problem is I create a lot of contingency when all builds assigned to the same agent are queued up. They wait in line until the previous build is done.

In an ideal world any agent should be able to take care of any build, but the source code being compiled has to be the same, regardless of the agent.

I tried changing the working folder of all agents to point to the same location but I get an error because two agents can't be mapped to the same folder. I guess there is one workspace per agent.

Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with @Jason Williams - it is not clear why you would want multiple agents from the way you have described the problems. The point of having multiple agents is to build in parallel and his options are well thought-out; it has been a few months since you posted this - have you made any changes to your process since then?  Either way, how is it going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do this. Here are all the changes you need to do:

- By default the working folder of each agent is $(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath). That means there's one working folder per BuildAgentId. I changed it so that all Agents share the same folder: $(SystemDrive)\Builds\WorkingFolder\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
- By default at runtime the workflow creates a workspace that looks like "[BuildDefinitionId]*[AgentId]*[MachineName]". Because all agents share the same working folder there's an error trying to create each separate workspace. The solution to this is in the build definition: Edit the xaml and look for an activity called "Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control". There's a property called WrokspaceName. Since I want to have one workspace per build definition I set that property to the BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.Name.
- Save your customized build template and create a build that uses it.
- Make sure the option "1. TF VersionControl/1. Clean workspace" is set to False. Otherwise the build will wipe out all the source code on every build.
- Make sure the option "2. Build/3. Clean build" is set to false. Otherwise the build will wipeout the output binaries on every build.

With this setup you can queue up the same build on any agent, and all of them will point to the same source code and bin output. When the source code changes only the affected binaries are recompiled. I have a custom step in the template that deploys the output files to IIS, to all the servers in our webfarm, using msdeploy.exe. Now my builds+deployments take one or two minutes, because only the dlls or content that changed during the build are synchronized to the servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run two build agents in the same folder. The point of build agents is to run multiple builds in parallel, usually on separate PCs. If you try to run them on the same source code, then (a) it's pointless as two build of exactly the same source should produce identical results, and (b) they are almost certainly going to trip over each other and cause the builds to fail or produce unexpected results.

If you want to be able to build and then deploy a series of versions of your codebase, then there are two options:

- if you queue up multiple builds, then the last one will "win", so the intermediate builds are of no real value. So if you check in New code before your first build completes, you may as well stop the active build and start a new one. you should be asking yourself why the build is so slow, or why you are checking in changes so often that this is necessary.
- if each build produces an incremental update to the deployed result, then you need to pass the output of your builds to some deployment agent that is able to diff it against the deployed version and send only the changes to be deployed. This could be set up to gather results from multiple build agents if that would be beneficial.
- but I wonder if perhaps your build Is slow because you are doing a complete build each time (which cleans the build folder, gets all the sources, and does a full rebuild), when what you want is an incremental build (which gets the latest changes, compiles only what is affected, and complete quickly). perhaps you should investigate making your build incremental.

Comment: Regarding bullet 1, I should clarify I don't want the same build definition to build simultaneously on several agents. I use rolling build triggers to keep only one build running at a time. Under those circumstances agents won't trip over each other. For bullet 2, assuming I invoke msdeploy.exe as a separate step of the workflow, I think I'll run into the same issue; datetimes won't match across outputs from different agents and it will deploy more files than necessary. Regarding bullet 3, I don't clean the build folder. The build itself is very fast. The time-consuming activity is deployment

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding your problem. If you can build quickly, but deployment is slow, and deployment overwrites the previous version, then the options sound like: kill intermediate build as they well be overwritten anyway; examine why your deployment is so very slow (can you upgrade the link to your server? can you compress the deployment files? etc)