# TFS Continuous Integration Build Trigger only one project not depending projects

Tags: tfs, project, integration, continuous

I have one special requirements setting up a build definition in TFS 2012.
I have a big solution with 26 depending projects. Lets assume we call these project A to Z.
Lets assume the build ordering is first to build A, then to build B, because B depends on A, then to build C, because it depends on A and B an so on ...

```
A

B <- A

C <- A,B

..

Z <- A,B,C,D,...,Y
```

My plan is to have 26 different build definitions in order to setup continous integration. 
Then a build should be started just in case a related project's sourcecode has changed.

For instance if I change project C, I do not want that A and B are build before.
But that's not possible, because the build definiton of C needs a workspace setup with A, B and C, otherwise C won't compile.

My question is now: How can I build just those project with CI which actually has changed?

Comment: are you asking how to do incremental builds in CI?

Comment: sometimes its hard to find the correct term for a specific problem but it seems that incremental builds is the term I was looking for. But there is a further question because incremental builds could be the solution. If I use several build agents, how can incremental builds work, if the build controller decides which agent he will use. If it switches all the time and I have 4 agents, the agent will get the newest sourccode for all depending projects minimum 4 times?

Comment: The agent will get the appropriate source code when it's chosen to run a build. If it isn't chosen, it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going into the build definition, Process tab. Under Basic, change Clean Workspace to None. This will setup incremental builds. This is similar to Build in visual studio vs Rebuild in visual studio. It will only rebuild the things that have changed.

Comment: how does it work with several build agents? Each build agent has its own working space

Comment: Each agent has its own directory on the build server where it gets all current sourcecode from sourcecontrol in order to compile it. In my specific scenario it is located in C:\build\$agentnr$\...
If the controller chooses randomly which agent it will take, agent 1 will download the sourcecode into the folder C:\build\1\... there it initially builds project A, B and C because its the first time. If I trigger the build the second time, the controller will e.g. choose agent 2. Therefore agent 2 will download the source into C:\build\2\... and therefore incremental build won't work.

Comment: this guy has exactly the same issue: [build-agents-sharing-common-build-folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755219/tfs-2013-build-agents-sharing-common-build-folder). I think he gave the correct answer but I have to start thinking how to set it up right now ... and if there could be any further issues ...

Comment: I believe that the build definition, once run the first time, will build in the same location for subsequent builds of that particular build definition so what I am saying in my answer should still be relevant.

Comment: sorry but it is still that way that the controller randomly chooses a new agent each time a build definition is triggered (like load balancing). I've tested it. You cannot be sure which agent it will be, but of course you helped me by mentioning the incremental builds. it's definitely the solution but in this case with further issues

Comment: I found an option in the build process template to force using a specific build agent, that's the solution. Without this option the controller still chooses the agent randomly. But one further question: If I change the code of project A, msbuild still rebuilds project B to Z!?!? How can I deny that. I thought incremental build will solve that. If I change project Z, then it works that only project Z is rebuild

Comment: In tfs you can give build agents tags and then in the build definition you can say use this specific agent (that's why I forgot my agents always use the same folders). It will build everything the first time but it shouldn't be updating the outputs if you set it up for incremental build. If you have any process that touches everything however (such as updating a shared assembly version) then  everything will get built every time.